# Multitouch two imageviews at the same position

Tags: android, imageview, multi-touch

I am using two image views in my activity, and the moment i double tap/pinch zoom i am zooming only the image which i have touched. 
how can i zoom the other image also exactly at same time & same position.

I am only achieving multi-touch/pinch zoom only on one image view.

PS: I searched before posting, but to no avail.

Because of code lenth i cant paste it. Here's the link for the same which i have used: [TouchImageView.java](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)

Comment: what gesture detector are you using?

Comment: OnDoubleTap of GestureDetector class in android

Comment: so `onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)` contains some code that zooms in/out your `imageView`, right? then simply apply the same code to second `ImageView`

Comment: I think you got it wrong. I can obviously do same thing for second imageview too, but my question is how do i zoom both imageviews at same time when i just double tap on only one image.

Comment: @pskink updated question plz check. Actually i am kinda detecting & showing changes of a single image in two imageviews

Comment: compatPostOnAnimation code?

Comment: Yes @MarcosVasconcelos , TouchImageView code by mike ortiz

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
onYourOnTouchImplementation(MotionEvent e) {
    //your implementation
    ...
    long downTime = e.getDownTime();
    long eventTime = e.getEventTime();
    int action = e.getAction();
    int x = e.getX() + (otherView.getX() - firstView.getX());
    int y = e.getY() + (otherView.getY() - firstView.getY());
    int metaState = e.getMetaState();

    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, action, x, y, metaState);
    otherView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

So you can pass touches on the second view.

Answer (score 1):

On your TouchImageView add:

```
TouchImageView other;
public void setOther(TouchImageView other) {
    this.other = other;
}
```

So in your activity.onCreate:

```
TouchImageView one = //findViewById
TouchImageView two = //findViewById
one.setOther(two);
two.setOther(one);
```

And add to the listener of the double tap a copy of the event to the other one:

```
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {    
    other.onDoubleTap(MotionEvent.obtain(e));
```

Comment: Tried this @Marcos but second image not getting zoomed

Comment: Maybe you will need to deliver in the onTouchEvent instead of doubletap is the view want something about the ON_DOWN, its a big code to look at for now